# Example of: Two researchers working on the same question but get opposite conclusions

Tags: mathematicians, philosophy-of-science, scientific-method

I wish to know about whether such example exists, could someone please help and tell me some stories about this?

p.s: Also I wonder why such thing can happen. I wish the two main characters in the story to be researchers of the same level. The only thing I can think of that makes this happen is that they are using different methods, but what else can make this happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this related to the "replication crisis" in social science research?  Such as psychology?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_crisis

Comment: Whether light is made of particles (Newton) or waves (Huygens, Euler)? Whether its vibrations are perpendicular to the plane of polarization (Fresnel), or parallel (Cauchy, Neumann)? Whether an electromagnetic field has momentum density $\smash{\mathbf{D\times B}}$ (Minkowski), or $\smash{\mathbf{E\times H}/c^2}$ (Abraham)? (Such questions, ultimately resolved by being made meaningless, are maybe not of the sort you want.)

Comment: How about the existence or non-existence of "Z-rays" ?  It's easy to get conflicting conclusions;  shortly thereafter one or both are shown to be wrong.

Comment: At the same time? During what time period? In what field? As it stands, the question is so broad one can write a book about it. Please narrow the scope.